# É possível alterar CSS no WebBrowser VB.NET?

Tags: .net, vb.net, navegador-de-internet

Olá, tudo bom pessoal? minha dúvida seguinte...

quero desabilitar todos os background-image então...

queria pegar no html de toda a página e coloca nada na tag "background-image" deixar sempre vazia.

nas imagens eu consegui.. estudei e achei

```
For Each img As HtmlElement In WebBrowser1.Document.Images
            img.SetAttribute("src", "")
            img.SetAttribute("style", "")
        Next
```

mais em relação ao css, não achei uma solução ainda.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para capturar todos os elementos da página:

```
Dim todosElementos As HtmlElementCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.All
```

E alterar o estilo:

```
For Each elemento As HtmlElement In todosElementos
   elemento.Style = "background-image: none"
Next
```

Comment: Creio que a questão é que o background pode estar em qualquer elemento, não só do tipo imagem.

Comment: Tem razão @mathiasfk ..